# C++ Isn't this a useless inline declaration?

Tags: c++, inline, private, member, protected

This is another question about inlining a function.
But I will take possible comments and answers right away:

1. Defining a function inside a class makes it inline automatically.
2. The same behaviour can be achieved by marking a function with inline
   outside of the class.
3. An inline function doesn't have to be inlined. It is
   completly up to the compiler to inline it.

**Now, my question:**
When inlining a function means to copy the body to the place where it is being called. 
Isn't it right to assume that the compiler will not inline it if it accesses private or protected members? 
The programm would literally not be able to access the members right?

I want to know that because to me it must look quite weird if someone inlines a function that <s>obviously</s> cannot be inlined.

*Here is an example:*

```
//Declaration
class Controller
{
public:
    bool bHasTarget();

private:
    const Object* pTarget;
};


//Definition
inline bool Controller::bHasTarget(){
    return !(pTarget == nullptr); //<- This cannot be inlined...Can it?
}
```

Comment: Well first of all you have a typo, that should be `==`.

Comment: compiler can access anything, so it can inline anything it wants (as long as it sees it, and here pTarget is visible to compiler)

Comment: Regarding the first point, I think you mean *defining* the function, not only declaring it.

Comment: I am not native english speaker, but I am pretty sure that "an inline function may not be inlined" would better read "an inline function may be not inlined"

Comment: And what the compiler "copies" when it inlines code is not actual source code, but inserts either some kind of abstract representation or generated code at the place of the function call. And why wouldn't it be able to inline functions accessing private/protected members? Then what would be the point of inline member functions? The compiler still won't allow code outside of the class to access private/protected members, so that looks to me like a good candidate for inlining.

Comment: Inline is not a "copy the code". It just means it will not generate a function call, and, instead, will generate the machine code for the function directly where it was called. Access restrictions are a thing on compilation time, not on runtime.

Comment: as I understand, the member function always gets a `this` pointer as parameter (if its not a static function) and as such it can access private members of `this` (whether inline or not). I think private access has nothing to do with inlining. Maybe i am wrong, would be glad to get corrected ;)

Comment: @tobi: "an `inline` function may not be inlined": you are right that this is ambiguous. But your version doesn't fix the problem. I would say "An `inline` function doesn't have to be inlined."

Comment: @TonyK Even better. Anyhow, I think he should fix it because it might be confusing

Comment: @NoelWidmer What about "A function declared as inline doesnt have to be inlined by the compiler". "inline function" is still ambiguous, as it can mean "function declared as inline" or "function inlined by the compiler". I hope there is some rule on this naming convention but unfortunately i didnt find any yet.

Comment: @tobi303 I am not sure why this is ambiguous. Feel free to edit yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Compiler can Access everything. The restrictions are only valid for the programmer. This means there are no restrictions for the **Compiler** to Access any variables! At the end every variable is just translated to an address which can be accessed. So for the Compiler it is no Problem to inline the code you provided!

There are also some "cheats" to Access private variables as a programmer. e.g

```
struct foo
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

...
foo test;
int *cheat = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&test);
cheat[0] = 1;    //This would Change a
...
```

Comment: Ah, I understand your cheat. (Are you sure you change a and not b?) But for this you would need to know how foo is constructed I guess. Well, thanks. I am not yet aware of how the compiler works but this is good to know :)

Comment: Yes this would Change a. `cheat[1]` would Change b

Answer (score 1):

> An inline function may not be inlined by the compiler. It is completly up to the compiler to inline it.

Compiler *may* inline but it might not. It's not guaranteed to.

> Isn't it right to assume that the compiler will not inline it if it accesses private or protected members?

No, it's not right to assume so. Accessing private or protected members does not prevent inlining.

> The programm would literally not be able to access the members right?

The program is literally able to access private and protected members. The function is a member, whether it's inlined or not.

To elaborate a bit, the compiler checks that the program does not break the access rules before any inlining optimization is done. After the check is passed, the access specifiers have zero meaning to the produced program and does not limit any optimization.

The example function can be inlined.